# Only include script for the first time, (sessioin storage)

Tags: javascript, flash, session, session-storage

I have a senario where i want to check if flash is installed or not. And if it is not installed then give a notification. The code is running fine.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js'> </script>

<div id="flashplayer-notification" style="display:inline-block;"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var FlashExists = swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion('1') ? true : false ;
   if (FlashExists) {
    document.getElementById("flashplayer-notification").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>No flash player installed</div>";
   }
</script>
```

But i think that its too much over kill to include a script everytime a person refreshes. We already know if he installed the player he will need to restart the browser so we can get the status on the next refresh. Here is the code that works.

```
if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
    if (FlashExists) {
    document.getElementById("flashplayer-notification").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>No flash player installed</div>";
   }
}
```

But there is no point in just adding the condition, we also need to include the script. How can i include the javascript file from within the session storage condition?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: In a second time, normally the file will be loaded from the cache, and I think that you are not using it only to verify if Flash Player exist or not !

Comment: thanks akmozo, you got me wondering now :P